# Want `&shy;` to be always visible

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web app and users sometimes paste in things they've copy/pasted from other places and that input may come with the `&shy;`  character (0xAD).   I don't want to filter it out, I simply need the user to see that there is an invisible character there, so they have no surprises later.

Does anyone know a way to make the `&shy;` always be visible? To show a hyphen, rather than remain hidden?   I suspect a custom web font might be needed, if so, does anyone know of a pre-existing one?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to either use JavaScript or a custom typeface that has a visible glyph for [the soft-hyphen character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen). Given the impracticalities of working with typefaces for the web (and burdening the user with an additional hundred-kilobyte download) I think the JavaScript approach is best, like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(domReadyEvent) {

    var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
    for(var i=0;i<textBoxes.length;i++) {

        textBoxes[i].addEventListener("paste", function(pasteEvent) {
            var textBox = pasteEvent.target;
            textBox.value = textBox.value.replace( "\xAD", "-" );
        } );
    }

} );
```